# preact build does not work when Webpack 5 is installed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preact, preact-cli

I'm working on a production Preact application that also uses Webpack. In that project, trying to run `preact build <args>` from an npm build script failed.

Following that, I created a minimal Preact application using `npx preact-cli create default preact-test`, installed Webpack 5, and now `preact build` throws the following error, which is the same one I was trying to reproduce:

```
Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/MultiEntryPlugin'
Require stack:
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/babel-esm-plugin/src/index.js
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/webpack/webpack-client-config.js
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/preact-cli/lib/lib/webpack/run-webpack.js
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/preact-cli/lib/commands/build.js
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/preact-cli/lib/commands/index.js
- /Users/<my name>/projects/preact-test/node_modules/preact-cli/lib/index.js
```

I saw a post that Webpack 5 has deprecated this internal plugin, but that's the most useful info I've found anywhere. I would appreciate if anyone has a solution to resolving this issue.

Comment: Just as a note, there's no reason why you should be doing this. Preact-CLI is a preconfigured build tool that's ready to go. You can edit the configuration, but installing your own version of Webpack is not something that'd ever work. Preact-CLI and your own Webpack install are mutually exclusive. Have to pick only one.

Answer (score 2):

After giving this a day and researching it with fresh eyes, I found that this is simply not possible yet; the preact-cli team has not migrated to Webpack 5, and there are no immediate plans to do so: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli/issues/1579